# Rails 3: Looping through array of objects, ignoring the first object in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view i am trying to dispaly a table of objects, this is my code:

```
<div id='categories_show'>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Categories</th>
      <th>CBB's</th>
    </tr>
    <% for category in @critical_process.categories %>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="<%= category.capability_building_blocks.size %>"><%= category.category_title %></td>
          <td><%= category.capability_building_blocks.first.cbb_title %></td>

        </tr>
        <% (category.capability_building_blocks - category.capability_building_blocks.first).each do |cbb| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= cbb.cbb_title %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

  </table>
</div>
```

however this is throwing an error saying: `can't convert CapabilityBuildingBlock into Array`

the relationships are correct, the error is coming from the line where i try subtract the first object of the array here: `<% (category.capability_building_blocks - category.capability_building_blocks.first).each do |cbb| %>`

is there any way i can loop through the array ignoring the first object in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using Array.drop - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000294

```
<% category.capability_building_blocks.drop(1).each do |cbb| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= cbb.cbb_title %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Most ruby functions like that return the altered elements and not the new array. I'll definitely have to use this sometime.

Comment: Yes, it's quite nice. And it's pretty obvious what's happening. Personally I don't like this array index mumbo jumbo, I always get it wrong... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, this is more readable (And I'm 80% sure it works):

```
<%= category.capability_building_blocks[1..-1].each do |cbb| %>
```

You can use the built in slice operators to select any elements from an array that you want. `-1` represents the last element in the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= (category.capability_building_blocks - [category.capability_building_blocks.first]).each do |cbb| %>
```

**Also...**

```
stop_here = category.capability_building_blocks.length
category.capability_building_blocks[1..(stop_here)].each do |cbb|
```

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer, but I personally like Chuck's better.

Comment: All great answers but i think HenningJ answer slightly edges infront.